# R Linear interpolation between two data sets

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm new to R and seeking for some advise on how to interpolate between two data tables and printing the outcome in a new column to "table1"

Table1:

```
   > (Table1 <- read.csv2("~/R/Table1.txt",sep=""))
  WindSpeed Degrees Direction
1      7.68    58.9       ENE
2      5.09    63.2       ENE
3      7.56    72.2       ENE
4      8.39    73.8       ENE
5      7.34    73.1       ENE
6      7.83    74.9       ENE
7      8.42    73.8       ENE
8      7.70    85.5         E
9      2.58    75.6         E
```

Table2:

```
> (Table2 <- read.delim("~/R/Table2.txt")[-1,])
   Wind.speed    Output
2         0,5      0
3         1,5      0
4         2,5  1.540
5         3,5  5.938
6         4,5 13.747
7         5,5 25.740
8         6,5 42.939
9         7,5 66.301
10        8,5 96.087
```

Now I want to take the Table1$WindSpeed values where Direction=="ENE" and interpolate between Table2$Wind.speed values to print interpolated Table2$Output values into a new column Table1$Output.

So what I have been trying to do is:

```
(Table1 <-
  transform(
    Table1, Output =
      ifelse(
        Direction == "ENE",
        approx(
          Table2$Wind.speed,Table2$Output,xout=Table1$Output, method = "constant"), "Næsta átt")
  )
)
```

But something is wrong and I get:

```
  WindSpeed Degrees Direction                             Output
1      7.68    58.9       ENE          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2      5.09    63.2       ENE NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
3      7.56    72.2       ENE          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
4      8.39    73.8       ENE NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
5      7.34    73.1       ENE          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
6      7.83    74.9       ENE NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
7      8.42    73.8       ENE          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
8      7.70    85.5         E                          Næsta átt
9      2.58    75.6         E                          Næsta átt
```

Anybody out there who could help me?

Ok a little update:
The answere I got earlier was really helpful but I want to find the values between given Table2$Output, for example for

```
windspeed= 7,68 

    > 66.301+(96.087-66.301)*(7.68-7.5)/(8.5-7.5)
    # [1] 71.66248
```

I therefore can't use "constant" and since my Output data isn't linear I cant use "linear"... any help here? :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fit a model to the data in Table2 and use this model to predict for Table1? However, if you still want to interpolate, you should probably use `approxfun`.

Comment: You're probably corret, approx dosnt work since i'm aiming for an output values between given output values with nonlinear data. I have Updatet the question would you mind explaning your idea on a solution further? :)

Answer (score 0):

There's just two small errors in your code:

1. change `xout` to `Table1$WindSpeed` (if I understand your question correctly)
2. extract the y values from the approx output with `$y`

So:

```
Table1 <-
  transform(
    Table1, Output =
      ifelse(
        Direction == "ENE",
        approx(
          Table2$Wind.speed, Table2$Output, xout = Table1$WindSpeed, method = "constant")$y, "Næsta átt")
  )

> Table1
  WindSpeed Degrees Direction    Output
1      7.68    58.9       ENE    66.301
2      5.09    63.2       ENE    13.747
3      7.56    72.2       ENE    66.301
4      8.39    73.8       ENE    66.301
5      7.34    73.1       ENE    42.939
6      7.83    74.9       ENE    66.301
7      8.42    73.8       ENE    66.301
8      7.70    85.5         E Næsta átt
9      2.58    75.6         E Næsta átt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `approxfun`:

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "   Wind.speed    Output
                 2         0,5      0
                 3         1,5      0
                 4         2,5  1.540
                 5         3,5  5.938
                 6         4,5 13.747
                 7         5,5 25.740
                 8         6,5 42.939
                 9         7,5 66.301
                 10        8,5 96.087")
DF1$Wind.speed <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", DF1$Wind.speed, fixed = TRUE))


fun <- approxfun(DF1$Wind.speed, DF1$Output)
fun(7.68)
#[1] 71.66248

DF2 <- read.table(text = "  WindSpeed Degrees Direction
                  1      7.68    58.9       ENE
                  2      5.09    63.2       ENE
                  3      7.56    72.2       ENE
                  4      8.39    73.8       ENE
                  5      7.34    73.1       ENE
                  6      7.83    74.9       ENE
                  7      8.42    73.8       ENE
                  8      7.70    85.5         E
                  9      2.58    75.6         E")

DF2$Output <- NA
DF2[DF2$Direction == "ENE", "Output"] <- fun(DF2[DF2$Direction == "ENE", "WindSpeed"])
#  WindSpeed Degrees Direction   Output
#1      7.68    58.9       ENE 71.66248
#2      5.09    63.2       ENE 20.82287
#3      7.56    72.2       ENE 68.08816
#4      8.39    73.8       ENE 92.81054
#5      7.34    73.1       ENE 62.56308
#6      7.83    74.9       ENE 76.13038
#7      8.42    73.8       ENE 93.70412
#8      7.70    85.5         E       NA
#9      2.58    75.6         E       NA
```

However, it might be better to develop a proper model for `Output` instead of interpolating.